# module config for path and shim

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm building an AMD module which uses multiple libraries with globals from a subfolder. Too reduce code and prevent globals leaking I want to use a config, but it seems the require config is only usable in the global context (how ironic)?!

What I want to do inside my module is basically this:

```
define(['require'], function(require) {
  require.config({
    baseUrl: 'sub/directory/',
    paths: {
      libfoo: 'libfoo23.min',
    },
    shim: {
      libfoo: {
        exports: 'Foo'
    }
  });
  require(['libfoo'], function(Foo) {});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

And there is a good reason for it: If the module loading configuration is defined *inside* a module that requires the configuration to be loaded, who comes first? It's a chicken and egg problem.

RequireJS tries to minimize global pollution; it succeeds in that by introducing just 2 globals, required for bootstrapping (`require()` and `define()`).

Comment: But doesn't that basically mean that a module is not able to shim its dependencies. I don't quite get how that is a good thing?!

Comment: That's right, a module cannot shim his own dependencies. This is a hurdle for me too, but at the same time, it prevent a module from being included twice in the final build

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it this way.

**config.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'sub/directory/',
    paths: {
      libfoo: 'libfoo23.min',
    },
    shim: {
      libfoo: {
        exports: 'Foo'
    }
});
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
define([ 'config' ], function() {
    require([ 'main' ]);
});
```

And in the HTML, I bootstrap this way:

```
<script data-main="/public/app/bootstrap" src="~/public/vendor/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

Everything else (the app) start in `main.js`

Comment: This way you would operate on the global require object and the global config, which is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Require config are global. You can only create sub require object, but that is a pretty narrow use case (never used it out of unit testing concerns).